# C# Settings with One Click Deployment

Tags: c#, deployment, publish, settings.settings

I have several settings in my C# application. One is to show a dialog (bool setting called ShowUpdate). By default I have this value set to true. The user can change this setting in the application to false. I want to default its value to true every time a publish a new version of the application. How do I do this?

Right now if the user sets it to false when I publish a new version of the application the setting does not get overwritten to true.

Comment: Set the value to true after calling `Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade()` and before calling `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()`

Comment: That's odd - I'd expect it to be defaulting when a new version is loaded, because it should be ignoring the old version. Here's a thought: Are you updating your AssemblyVersion (in AssemblyInfo.cs) as well as the publish version? The settings version is determined by AssemblyVersion, not by publish version. (Unless you're calling Default.Upgrade(), and then see Stuart's answer above!)

Comment: @StuartDunkeld Would that not always set the value to true every time the user runs the program?

Comment: No I am not updating my assembly version, is there an article on doing this?

Comment: @user2054760 you only call `Upgrade()` when there's a new version - using a technique like this - http://www.ngpixel.com/2011/05/05/c-keep-user-settings-between-versions/ - if you don't call `Upgrade()` then the user settings don't get migrated and the new default is set (see Matthew's comment)